# 19.10: After apt upgrade and restart, sound fails

Tags: upgrade, sound, alsa

Not even ALSA's `aplay` is working right, it seems there are `no soundcards` (though this is a laptop), alsamixer won't open, pulse only has dummy outputs, and I'm worried now. I have a feeling that http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=6e811dfc5729d266a1931a7e9c5b7bec57118312 may be useful.

I'm on linux kernel version 5.3.0-41-generic and Ubuntu 19.10,
I don't really know what changed as it was just a regular package upgrade, I didn't pay much attention to it.

`sudo lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
```

It sees a multimedia audio controller.

What went so wrong!

Comment: How do I find out which version I was on?

Comment: Now, please do `sudo lspci`, copy the result, then return here, click [edit], and paste the result into the question. This preserves the formatting of the result; please don't use Add Comment because it loses formatting.

Comment: no i was on 19.10 before and 19.10 now

Comment: are you going to leave me stranded here? I gave the info!

Comment: I'm going to try booting from a different kernel version, as i think the kernel version changed.

Comment: We're all volunteers here, giving of our time to help. I don't know the cause of the problem, but sometimes I do know how to find the information needed by others who do. When someone who knows the solution sees the post, they will provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

## It was the kernel's fault.

just booted using 5.3.0-41-generic.
Sound now works again. The moral of this story, I guess, is that: when you do an update, and something seems wrong, it could be the fault of the kernel!